# How to solve an error while cloning a github repository

Tags: github

I have a repository in github. But I can't clone it. Whenever I try to do so, it says.

```
fatal: destination path 'repo_name' already exists and is not an empty directory.
```

before anyone starts saying it is an empty repository, I'm saying it a repository which has files

any answer is appreciated
thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This message says that you already have a folder with your project name on the clone destination.

For instance if your GitHub URL is https://github.com/user/myProject.git, by default the clone command will try to create a directory named `myProject`.

Check the folders of your clone directory or change the name by doing :

`git clone https://github.com/user/myProject.git MyNewFolderName`

Comment: thanks for the answer...just another thing..how can i delete a directory from google cloud shell?

Comment: No Idea, never used Google Cloud shell

Comment: Thanks a lot for the attempt...I have recently researched on it and the command for it is rm -r (for anyone who is visiting this thread for any help)